# PLSQL Grant on Tables used on a package

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, sql-grant

I have two procedures one defines and uses a CURSOR with table from another schema and it gives me an error of insufficient privileges; the other one, creates a table with a dynamic SQL, referencing the same tables, but goes without error,

why so?

First procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE SCHEMA1.PROCEDURE proc1 AS
TYPE Record1 IS RECORD (v_one VARCHAR2(20), v_two VARCHAR2(20)); 
CURSOR procCursor RETURN Record1 IS
SELECT P.CODE, R.DESCRIPTION
FROM SCHEMA2.ROLES771 R, SCHEMA2.ROLEP773 P
WHERE ...;

BEGIN
...
END SCHEMA1.PROCEDURE;
```

The other one, without error is this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA1.PROCEDURE proc1 AS
TYPE Record1 IS RECORD (v_one VARCHAR2(20), v_two VARCHAR2(20)); 
CURSOR procCursor RETURN Record1 IS
SELECT P.CODE, R.DESCRIPTION
FROM TMP_TBL;

BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('TRUNCATE TABLE TMP_TBL');
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('
INSERT INTO TMP_TBL (ONE, TWO) 
SELECT P.CODE, R.DESCRIPTION
FROM SCHEMA2.ROLES771 R, SCHEMA2.ROLEP773 P');
...
END SCHEMA1.PROCEDURE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, tables are owned by *someone else* (i.e. another user).

Problem you described is often result of you being granted privileges via **role**. Such privileges work at SQL level or in anonymous PL/SQL blocks, but won't work in named PL/SQL procedures (functions, procedures, packages, triggers).

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm) says

> The EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement executes a dynamic SQL statement or anonymous PL/SQL block

(yes, I know, this is 10g document; later versions say that it "builds and runs a dynamic SQL statement in a single operation" which isn't that descriptive).

Basically, that's why `execute immediate` runs OK.

---

What to do? Let another user grant privileges **directly** to you, not via role.